# Asp.Net Mvc Hidden Field from Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I thought this would be a quick search on google but maybe I'm missing something. Is there a way, using Data Annotations, to set a ViewModel property to create a HiddenInput when the markup get rendered?

The only annotations I've found were to hide the property from the view entirely, I still want the property rendered but as a hidden input.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

This property:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

will be rendered as i.e.

```
<input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="21" />
```

when using `Html.EditorForModel()` or  `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Id)`

Comment: Fully qualify with System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput or add the namespace.

Comment: Thanks, it worked well except Id property. I haven't known why, of course there was completely no validation attribute for Id property in my code.

Comment: Is there any reason why one would not use the html helper `@Html.hiddenfor(_ => _.FOO) ` in the view?

Comment: @gerdi you may want to leave the views (the .cshtml) alone and control the output by the model attributes only. Or you may wish to use @Html.EditorForModel() in which case you're not writing Razor code, and so you'd need the attribute.